# MS Access ODBC Connection to SQL Server Over the internet slow

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I was using ODBC connection to create DSN less connection to SQL Server from my access database:

```
myConnectionString = "ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=DESKTOP-DAVE\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=MY_DB;Trusted_Connection=Yes"
Set td = CurrentDb.CreateTableDef(stLocalTableName, 0, stRemoteTableName, myConnectionString)
```

This is super fast and it will connect my 50 tables within seconds

Now, I want to connect to a SQL Server over the internet:

```
 myConnectionString ="ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=42.152.1.10,1433;DATABASE=MY_DB;Trusted_Connection=Yes"
Set td = CurrentDb.CreateTableDef(stLocalTableName, 0, stRemoteTableName, myConnectionString)
```

This however takes around 2 seconds per table connection.

Is this an acceptable delay for SQL Server over the internet? Is there a way I can modify my connection string to make this process faster?

It would have been fine if just connecting tables took longer. But the thing is all of my forms that are attached to these tables are super slow as well.

Comment: A very simple question. Your low cost network is either a 100BaseT or now MORE likely a 1000BaseT network. What is the speed of your internet connection you are using? That 1000baseT network is likely what 50 times faster? So, divide 2 seconds over 50, and we get 0.04 of a second to link a table on your local network. So simply divide out the 2 speeds and add them to your post (5 times, 20 times - what is the difference - a super simple question). Never was a good reason to re-link each time on startup - that can be slow (we have 600 tables to link). So only re-link if connection has changed.

Comment: Your internet connection speed matters for large data transfers. Internet vs. LAN connections can also nail you on lots of small data transfers due to latency, e.g.: an office LAN will typically have <2 ms latency for requests but over internet connections you'll typically see <60 ms latency for intra-country or <250 ms latency for inter-continental.

Comment: I was using cleardb mysql database which is on the internet as well before. But it was not this bad. Over the internet maybe it was 0.7 seconds per table. It got a lot slower with SQL database so I thought it might be something to do with my connection string. I have combo box drop down with row source which takes 2 seconds to drop down. Once the combo box is selected I query another table to get some data which takes 3-4 seconds and so on ..

Comment: While not a direct answer to your question, you may find the following advice when using Access with ODBC helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/optimize-odbc-data-sources

Comment: this is about grade 3 math. You take the network speed you had before, and then divide it by the internet speed you have. Without this grade 3 math, then we are ALL in the dark. So, if the speed difference is 40x? Then 2 seconds now becomes 80 seconds. WE NEED that number. We MUST have that number. Simply POST the result of that grade 3 math. (don't need bits, or bytes or units). Post JUST the result of this SIMPLE number. So, post that ratio. Post the result of the speed divide number please. We ONLY need the result of the speed divide number. ONE simple number is ALL we ask for.